# What is the relative path for data files as shown below?

Tags: java, filenames, relative-path, pathname

**EDIT**: I want this to work not only in the IDE (when it runs from the root directory) but also when I run it from Terminal (I have `cd`'d into the `src` directory.

I have a file called `main.java.org.name.nlp.lg.Class`, which is in the `src` directory. Outside the `src` directory (in the root directory), I have a folder called `data` which contains the file `data/en/words/file.txt`. How can I load `file.txt` into `Class.java` via a relative path? My current code gives me a NPE:

```
URL url = new Class().getClass().getResource("../../../../../../../data/en/words/file.txt");
File f = new File(url.getPath());
List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath());
System.out.println(list);
```

Here is the file tree:

```
src
  main
    java
      org
        name
          nlp
            lg
              Class
data
  en
    words
      file.txt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Path pathToYourFile = Paths.get(Paths.get("data/en/words").toAbsolutePath().toString(), 
                               "file.txt");

File yourFile = pathToYourFile.toFile();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me when I cd into the src directory and run it in terminal, but it works in the IDE. it is because when I am inside src/, there is no data folder. How can I make this work in both IDE and terminal src dir?

Comment: so if there's no data folder, where's the file located? You may have to implement some kind of if stamente for this

Comment: ok. how do I check what the folder I am currently in is?

Comment: I can't really know in where folder it is...can you copy it to a known one?

Comment: never mind, I figured it out. I used `System.getProperty("user.dir")`